# Synchronization of HTTP session refresh in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, session, synchronization

I am trying to make my HTTP session refresh function synchronous.
I am using RxJava and Retrofit.
This is my function stripted of some code for simplicity :

```java
public void refreshSession(){
  fetchNewSession(...).flatMap(response -> {
    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
       storeNewSessionId(response.headers().get("sessionId"));
       return Observable.empty();
    } else {
       throw new MyHTTPException(response);
    }
  }).doOnError(throwable -> {
     Thread.currentThread().interupt();
  }).blockingSubscribe();
}
```

So what I am trying to do is to synchronize this function so only one thread fetches new session while al other threads wait. This is some pseudo code of what I am trying to achive:

```java
public void refreshSession(){
  if(!sessionNotRefreshed){
    fetchNewSession();
  } else {
    wait();
  }
}
```

So when new HTTP requests are sent with expired session, I get response that session is invalid and block threads until session is refreshed after which HTTP requests are resent with refreshed session.
I tried following (this is probably very wrong and Joshua Bloch says in his book *Effective Java Programing* that we should use some higher level API for notify and wait):

```java
private final Object LOCK = new Object();
private volotile booleand sessionRefreshed = true;
public void refreshSession(){
   try {
     if(!sessionRefreshed){
        synchronized(LOCK){
           LOCK.wait();
        }
     } else {
       sessionRenewed = false;
       fetchNewSession(...).flatMap(response -> {
         if(response.isSuccessful()) {
           storeNewSessionId(response.headers().get("sessionId"));
           return Observable.empty();
         } else {
           throw new MyHTTPException(response);
         }
       }).doOnError(throwable -> {
         Thread.currentThread().interupt();
       }).blockingSubscribe();
    }
  } finally {
    synchronized (LOCK) {
      LOCK.notifyAll();
    }
    sessionRenewed = true;
  }
}
```

And this:

```java
private final CountDownLatch LOCK = new CountDownLatch(1);
private volotile booleand sessionRefreshed = false;
public void refreshSession(){
   if(!sessionRefreshed){
     sessionRenewed = true;
     fetchNewSession(...).flatMap(response -> {
       if(response.isSuccessful()) {
         storeNewSessionId(response.headers().get("sessionId"));
         return Observable.empty();
       } else {
         throw new MyHTTPException(response);
       }
     }).doOnError(throwable -> {
       Thread.currentThread().interupt();
     }).blockingSubscribe();
      LOCK.countDown();
      sessionRefreshed = false;
   } else {
     LOCK.await();
   }
}
```

But this only works for first invocations of threads because count reaches 0. I could reset the count by `LOCK = new CountDownLatch(1);` but I think CountDownLatch is not intended for such a thing. There are Condition and ReentrantLock API and Phaser API, but I am not sure how to use them.
And also I tried without synchronization:

```java
private final CountDownLatch LOCK = new CountDownLatch(1);
private volotile booleand sessionRefreshed = false;
public void refreshSession(){
   if(!sessionRefreshed){
     sessionRenewed = true;
     fetchNewSession(...).flatMap(response -> {
       if(response.isSuccessful()) {
         storeNewSessionId(response.headers().get("sessionId"));
         return Observable.empty();
       } else {
         throw new MyHTTPException(response);
       }
     }).doOnError(throwable -> {
       Thread.currentThread().interupt();
     }).blockingSubscribe();
      Schedulers.io().createWorker().schedule(() -> {
         sessionRefreshed = false;
      }, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   } else {
   }
}
```

Do not allow multiple threads to fetch session at the same time in period of 5 seconds.
Are any of these correct and is there a better solution?